# Matplotlib 3D with Multiple Axes

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot

**Setup and Background**

I have two sets of data, a black set and a color set, each of which lives on a separate plane but has some prescribed relationship between the two. I generated the following plot which is an attempt at including multiple grids in order to better visually identify each set of data with a different plane.

[image: Attempt at multiple 3D grids.]

The makeshift grids C_x and C_y were generated manually by sending appropriate `numpy.linspace()` and `numpy.meshgrid()` data to Matplotlib's `Axes3DSubplot.plot_wireframe()`. However, they don't necessarily align with the actual plot grids unless I muck around with the linspace data.

**My Question**

Is there a way to have an `Axes3DSubplot` object generate multiple x-y planar grids, in this case, one at `z=0` and the other at `z=1`? Additionally, is there a way to just remove the x-z and y-z grids once this is accomplished?

*I think the closest analogue in a 2d Matplotlib plot is the `Axes.twinx()` method ([example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/two_scales.html)).*

Comment: **Progress update** - looking at [this line](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/axes3d.py#L284) in `Axes3d.draw()` suggests that if I overwrite `Axes3d.xaxis.draw_pane()` and `Axes3d.yaxis.draw_pane()` then I might be able to achieve the desired results. Replacing these with `lambda renderer: None` removes the grey pane but not the grid lines.

Comment: **Progress update** - Also, `Axes3d.xaxis._PLANES` may have something to do with it, as seen from `xaxis.draw_pane()`.

Comment: Did you end up finding a solution, or at least a 3D version for `twinx()` in order to have multiple axes in 3D?

Comment: @ilke444 - Unfortunately, no. Then again, I haven't looked at this problem during the past four years. : )